# Telegram API "parseMode:MarkdownV2" doesn't change text style

Tags: python, telegram

so I try to use Telegram's API to send messages to a group. Sending messages is working, but when I try to send messages with a certain style,
for example bold, it just doesn't work.

My example message is: "* hello send help *".
It should look something like this: **hello send help**, but it just sends the literal (i.e the * shows in the message and it is not bold)

here's the code:
`

```
payload = {"parseMode": "MarkdownV2", "chat_id": chat_id, "text": "*Send help*"}
requests.post(f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{bot_token}/sendMessage", data=payload)
```

When trying to use parse_mode instead parseMode I just get error 400. What do I do wrong? I also tried to use "HTML" as parseMode but it still doesn`t work

Answer (score 2):

The parameter of [`sendMessage`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage) is specified as `parse_mode`, not `parseMode`. Try that.

Comment: Silly me, I tried to use parse_mode="markdown" at first and it didn't work, I didn't think that was happening because I needed to pass "MarkdownV2". Problem is solved, thank you!